# Android Application layout is out of place

Tags: android, xml

I've just started learning how to code android applications, but I have run into a problem with my layout. As you can see in the picture, my nav bar drawer icon is out of place. Is there anyway to fix this? I tried adding padding, it just adds a bit of white space, but my stuff are still being cut off. :-([image]

Comment: how is it out of place? thats just the old nav menu style

Comment: the part with the red arrow is too much to the left! i want a little bit more space from the left :-(

Comment: As I said that is how the old style nav menu icon is. if you want something different then use the new style with `Toolbar`